# How do I get my application's execution state?

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

How do I find out what execution state my Windows Phone Application is in?

I have been unable to find relevant information after searching the web and Microsoft's documentation.

Comment: what do you mean by execution state? You can do stuff only if the application is currently running. If it is suspended or terminated, then no code is executing.

Comment: On Android and iOS devices I can catch events when the application goes to the background or comes back to the Foreground. According to MS'documentation there are such Lifecycle events on WindowsPhone as well, but I can't find anything about how I can catch them.

Comment: What are you using to develop, C# or JavaScript? in C# there are the Application.Suspending and Application.Resuming events that you can handle to save and restore user state. Check here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh465115.aspx

Comment: I found the VisibilityChanged event now, which should be fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

check this out. You must use public ***enum ApplicationExecutionState***: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.activation.applicationexecutionstate(v=win.10).aspx